# Google Rejection because of "Violation of Broken Functionality policy"

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, proguard

The following problem keeps coming up when I try to regularly publish an updated version of my app to the Google Play Store:

**"Your app contains content that isn’t compliant with the Broken Functionality policy.
App loads, but crashes"**

According to R&D, the error I'm receiving following the results of the Firebase Test indicates that there may be a problem with the Proguard file on AWS.
**"Unrecognised suffix for the AWS http client class"**

Is there anyone who can assist me with this, or where should I go to find the solution to this issue?

Comment: check [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/236543572/violation-of-broken-functionality-policy?hl=en#:~:text=This%20could%20be%20a%20problem,properly%20on%20all%20of%20them.)

Comment: When we have a hard to reproduce problem which happen during google play publication (during testing phase), we add firebase logging and other analytics to get more information from the testing phase.